# Studio + java 6 + Snow Leopard

Tags: orientdb

For stability reasons (OS X stability) I decided to use 10.6.8 with java 6 again. When I try to use studio I get the following

```
2015-11-17 10:16:34:828 SEVERE Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Database 'XXXXX' is not configured on server (home=XXXXX/orientdb-community-2.0.12/databases/) [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
2015-11-17 10:16:41:062 SEVERE Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Database 'XXXX' is not configured on server (home=XXXXXX/orientdb-community-2.0.12/databases/) [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
```

And studio asks for the login info endlessly without showing any data.

Any workarounds? This didn't happen with mavericks and java 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after I eliminated the "." from the database dir name the severe error did not appear anymore.

But the endless credentials pop-up did not stop. Even when I managed to issue a "select from e", the query never returned.

BUT if I checked the "store pair in keychain" box everything started to work as always. It should not be mandatory.

Forget about this one

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no database under that path. Please check the database folder if exists or it's empty.

Comment: I just checked. Files are there.

Comment: Removed a '.' I had in the dir name. The severe error does not appear anymore but the endless login continues. I used a graph factory with no user data at creation time. I am providing the default credentials in the config file: root admin. Thanks!!!

Comment: Default credentials are admin/admin.